# How to determine if UIView is currently being touched?

Tags: uiview, touch

Is there a way I can query a UIView to determine if it currently being touched?  The reason I ask is because I am using "touchedBegan", "touchesEnded", and "touchesMoved" to keep a UIView under a user's finger.  However, if the user moves his/her finger really fast and manages to "escape" the window I want to remove that window.
I was thinking I could use a timer to periodically test each view to determine if it is currently being touched, if it is not, I will remove it.  An "IsTouchedProperty" would be perfect.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and solved it by using the `tracking` property. From the documentation:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is currently
>   tracking touches related to an event. (read-only)

This is a method on UIControl, but aren't you trying to create one?

You can also `hitTest` views. Check [the apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html)

Comment: Just a note that this isn't exactly correct. isTouchInside and isTracking aren't part of UIView. They're from UIControl

Comment: isTracking is also part of UIScrollView

Answer (score 3):

Since UIView doesn't inherit from UIControl you would need to subclass UIView and roll your own `isTouching` property using touch events. Something like:

```
// MyView.h
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isTouching;
@end


// MyView.m
...

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    self.isTouching = YES;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    self.isTouching = NO;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    self.isTouching = NO;
}
```